# Sobolev trace theorem for manifolds with boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, manifolds, sobolev-spaces

Can I get a reference to a trace theorem for a manifold $M$ with boundary $\partial M$, and I am hoping the inequality
$$\lVert Tu \rVert_{L^2(\partial M)} \leq c\lVert u \rVert_{H^1(M)}$$
will hold.

What does the manifold need to satisfy for it to hold?
Any help? Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with Sobolev spaces on manifolds, but I would guess that this could not hold. For ordinary domains $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$, you need at least the $H^{1/2}(\Omega)$-norm on the right hand side.

Comment: @gerw Sorry, that's a typo. I meant $H^1$. I edit.

Comment: Here's a reference: 
Li, Yanyan; Zhu, Meijun
Sharp Sobolev trace inequalities on Riemannian manifolds with boundaries. Comm. Pure Appl. Math. 50 (1997), no. 5, 449–487.

It's a sharp inequality, so it's probably more than you need.